# Why cron not outputting to file?

Tags: cron, io-redirection

I scheduled a cron task:

```
0 */10 * * * aapa bash /home/aapa/scripts/es_backup.sh &>> /var/log/super/es_backup.log
```

It is running as logged into syslog:

```
Dec  4 08:17:01 dexter CRON[15552]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec  4 09:17:01 dexter CRON[15564]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec  4 10:00:01 dexter CRON[15573]: (aapa) CMD (bash /home/aapa/scripts/es_backup.sh &>> /var/log/super/es_backup.log)
Dec  4 10:17:01 dexter CRON[15706]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

But there is nothing in the output file (/var/log/super/es_backup.log). I don't think there is any issue in file permissions as the file is created by the same use (`aapa`).

```
$ ls -la /var/log/super/es_backup.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 aapa aapa 14215 Dec  4 00:20 /var/log/super/es_backup.log
```

Also when I ran the same command (`bash /home/aapa/scripts/es_backup.sh &>> /var/log/super/es_backup.log`) manually the output is indeed written to the log file.

Also the command is completing successfully as I see the backup is complete.

**Not a duplicate**
This is not a duplicate to [Cron only occasionally sends e-mail on output and errors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225219/cron-only-occasionally-sends-e-mail-on-output-and-errors) as the I am not using `sh` as suggested in the answers. I am running the command in `bash` explicitly, so it should not be an issue of `&`.

Comment: @archemar its not a duplicate. I updated the reason in the question

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate. Read in [the other answers](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225219/cron-only-occasionally-sends-e-mail-on-output-and-errors) about the `&` character and the shell that `cron` is using to run your command.

Answer (score 1):

try changing to be like that

```
0 */10 * * * aapa bash /home/aapa/scripts/es_backup.sh >> /var/log/super/es_backup.log
```

Comment: As I said, _Also when I ran the same command (bash /home/aapa/scripts/es_backup.sh &>> /var/log/super/es_backup.log) manually the output is indeed written to the log file._, then why this is happening?

Comment: See the similar question from earlier -- cron -> sh -> & backgrounded -> output is lost

Comment: @JeffSchaller Its not a duplicate. I added the reason in the question

Comment: It's because you use bash and cron uses sh that you're seeing this behavior, @knoxxs.  Try putting your cron command into a #!/bin/bash script and see. Read all of the related Q's comments & answers.

Comment: @JeffSchaller the command I scheduled in cron is `bash /home/aapa/scripts/es_backup.sh &>> /var/log/super/es_backup.log` not `/home/aapa/scripts/es_backup.sh &>> /var/log/super/es_backup.log`. Doesn't this means that cron will eventually user bash (cron --> sh --> bash --> script). Also my script's first line is `#!/usr/bin/env bash` already.

Comment: Cron calls sh; sh sees the & and that's where it breaks down, because it doesn't understand the &>> bash-ism. Replace the bash-isms or wrap the whole thing in a simple sh script